# Characteristic equation on a particular curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Find the solution of $bg_x+g_y =  0$ which takes value of $g=e^{-{x^2}}$ on the line $y=-x$.

I cannot see how to incorporate the line in my solution as I am used to dealing with initial value problems like this.

Comment: b cannot equal 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
According to *Characteristic Method*: $\dot{x} = b$ and $\dot{y} = 1\quad\imp\totald{y}{x} = {1 \over b}\quad\imp\quad y - {x \over b} = \mbox{constant}$:
$$
{\rm g}\pars{x,y} = \fermi\pars{y - {x \over b}}\quad\imp\quad
\fermi\pars{-{b + 1 \over b}\,x} = \expo{-x^{2}}\quad\imp\quad
\fermi\pars{t} = \exp\pars{-\,{b^{2} \over \bracks{b + 1}^{2}}\,t^{2}}
$$
$$
\color{#00f}{\large{\rm g}\pars{x,y}} = \exp\pars{-\,{b^{2} \over \bracks{b + 1}^{2}}\,\bracks{y - {x \over b}}^{2}}
=\color{#00f}{\large\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{by - x}^{2} \over \bracks{b + 1}^{2}}}}
$$

Comment: Im assuming that your f's are actually g's.

Comment: I cannot see how the third implication works, how do you arrive with -(b+1)x/b

Comment: Replace $\displaystyle{t \equiv -\,{b + 1 \over b}\,x}$ yields $\displaystyle{x \equiv -\,{b \over b + 1}\,t}$. Just replace them.

Comment: $\displaystyle{y - {x \over b} = \mbox{constant}}$ means that $\displaystyle{{\rm g}\left(x,y\right)}$ depends on the combination $\displaystyle{y - {x \over b}}$: It's an 'arbitrary function' $\displaystyle{{\rm f}\left(y - {x \over b}\right)}$. $\displaystyle{{\rm f}}$ is determined by the condition $\displaystyle{{\rm g}\left(-x,x\right) = {\rm f}\left(\left[-x\right] - {x \over b}\right)  = {\rm e}^{-x^{2}}}$.

Comment: This is the [Method of Characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: In my comment before the last one there is a typo. It should be $\displaystyle{\bf{\rm g}\left(x,-x\right)}$ instead of $\displaystyle{{\rm g}\left(-x,x\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that $bg_x + g_y = 0$ implies that if we define the line $\mathbf{x}(s)=(a,-a)+(b,1)s$ with $a$ a constant, then by the chain rule $g$ is constant on these lines. As long as these lines aren't parallel to the initial data you've been given, that means that you can work out what value $g$ takes at a given point $(x,y)$ by working out which line of the above form $(x,y)$ lies on, and then seeing which point on $y=-x$ also lies on this line (call this point $(\gamma,-\gamma)$ - since $g$ is constant on these lines, $g(x,y)=g(\gamma,-\gamma)=e^{-\gamma^2}$.

The only thing left for you to do is algebraically express $\gamma$ in terms of x and y.